# CSS styling only works in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to teach myself web-design and am just starting to get the hang of the basics. I just finished the content of my practice web site for an imaginary restaurant, and was feeling pretty proud of it because it works perfectly in google chrome, but when I checked how it looked in IE and firefox it seems that the CSS styling isn't registering at all.

Here is the code for the home page. The site contains images and links to other pages as well, but my real concern is just getting the CSS to apply correctly across all browsers.

```css
/*    Created on : Mar 23, 2015, 3:16:56 PM
    Author     : Dan
*/
*{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
  header, nav, aside, article, footer, section {
  display: block;

  }

  figure{
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

  figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  padding: .5%;
  font-family: 'Smokum', Georgia, Serif;
  color: #952706;
  font-size: 6em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  }

  body{
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("Frontier_images/wood084.jpg");
  }

  body article{
  text-align: left;
  }

  header{
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:none;
  max-height: 99%;
  max-width: 99%;
  background-color: rgba(250,240,230,.0);
  }
  nav{
  margin:0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  border:solid 2px #4c2e16;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1%;
  }
  nav a{
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 14.28%;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkred;
  }

  nav a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: firebrick;
  }

  #mininav{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:2%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  padding: 1%;
  }

  #mininav a{
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 19%;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: .75em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }


  article a{
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Bitter', Georgia, Serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: darkred;
  }

  article a:hover{
    font-style: italic;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Bitter', Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: firebrick;
  }

  article a:visited{
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Bitter', Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: purple;
  }

  div * p {
    text-indent: 5%;
}

  #wrapper{
  width: 80%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: burlywood;
  box-shadow:-8px 8px 10px -1px black;
  padding: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

  #spillwrapper{
    width: 80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: firebrick;
    color: burlywood;
    box-shadow:-8px 8px 10px -1px black;
    padding: 2%;
    overflow: visible;
  }

  h1{
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: 'Smokum', Georgia, Serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  }

  a h1{
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Smokum', Georgia, Serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .menudrop{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  }

  .menudropitem{
  padding: 0 1%;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: rgba( 178,34,34,.7);
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Smokum', Georgia, Serif;
  }

   ul{
  list-style-position: inside;
  }

  hr{
   color: firebrick;
   margin-top:2em;
   margin-bottom: 2em;
   border-top: dotted 1px;
  }

  .column1{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5%;
  z-axis: 2;
  background-color: rgba(250,240,230, .7);
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .column2{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5%;
  z-axis: 2;
  background-color: rgba(250,240,230,.7);
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 33%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .center{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5%;
  z-axis: 2;
  background-color: rgba(250,240,230, .7);
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: georgia, serif, arial;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }

  footer{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: .5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  color: darkred;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-style: italic;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  }

  table.thumbs{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }

  table.thumbs td{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2px;
  }

  table.thumbs img.small{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  }

  /* Large images in left two columns */
  table.thumbs img.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
  }

  /* Large images in right two columns */
  table.thumbs img.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
  }


  /* Hover on any table cell */
 table.thumbs td:hover img.left,
 table.thumbs td:hover img.right,
 table.thumbs td:hover img.bottomright,
 table.thumbs td:hover img.bottomleft{
visibility: visible;
  }

  #imgleft{
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  }

  #imgleft img{
  margin-right: 6px;
  }

  #imgleft p{
  text-indent: 5%;
  margin-right: 45%;
  }

  #imgright{
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  }

  #imgright img{
  margin-left: 6px;
  }

  #imgright p{
  text-indent: 5%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  }

  #imgleft2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  float: left;
  }

  #imgleft2 img{
  margin-right: 6px;
  }

  #imgleft2 p{
  text-indent: 5%;
  margin-right: 45%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Frontier</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="frontierstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="css/text">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Smokum' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
        <body>
       <header>
           <figure>
             <img src="Frontier_images/eggskillet.jpg" alt="Egg Skillet">
             <figcaption>Frontier</figcaption>
           </figure>

        </header>
            <nav>
                <a href="frontiermenu.html">Menu</a>
                <a href="frontierevents.html">Events</a>
                <a href="frontiergallery.html">Gallery</a>
                <a href="frontierfamily.html">Our Family</a>
                <a href="frontierfaq.html">FAQ</a>
                <a href="frontiercontact.html">Contact Us</a>
                <a href="frontierdirections.html">Directions</a>
            </nav>
      <div id="wrapper">
              <article>
       <h1>
         Hours:
       </h1>
       <h2>
         Mon- Closed<br>
         Tues thru Sat- 6am until 1pm<br>
         Sun- 8am until 3pm
       </h2>
       </article>


        <section class=column1>
          <h1>
            Frontier's Concept
          </h1>
          <p>
        Frontier is the first franchise developed by former President of the U.S. Theodore Roosevelt.
        Teddy, as he is known to his friends and family, always had a dream of creating
        a breakfast house that captured the look and feel of a specific time and place that was
        very dear to him.</p>
        <p>
          Frontier is the realization of that dream. Tucked away in the heart of the pocono mountains,
          our establishment seeks to give our guests not only a delicious breakfast, but a completely immersive
          experience as well.</p>
          <br>
          <img src=Frontier_images/cabinflag.jpg>

</p>
</section>
        <section class=column2>
          <h1>
            Accolades
          </h1>
          <p>
"Killer food, great atmosphere and the friendliest chef."
~City Weekly
</p><br>
<p>
  "This might be the quintessential Northern PA restaurant.
    The antique log cabin radiates mountain hospitality and the beauty and
     bounty of the Poconos are apparent on each plate."
     ~Happenings Magazine
   </p><br>
   <p>
     "10 Best Restaurants in PA: Local Food and Fine Dining"
     ~The Culture Trip
   </p><br>
</section>



        </div>
            <footer>
            <p>
            Frontier Restaurant. All Rights Reserved.
          </p>
            </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me in FF

Comment: What do you mean it only works in Chrome? Do you mean none of the code works at all in other browsers? Of course it does. Do you mean it doesn't render the exact same way as Chrome?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer console? Any 404s or 500s? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: Looks fine to me also in the three browsers. The only thing noticeable is the <figcaption>Frontier</figcaption> which in absolute position will be hidden behind the top menu.. I don't know where the element is suppose to be positioned so I'll leave that to you

Comment: What happened was that I emailed the directory to myself so I could see how it looked on my desktop (I made the site using my laptop). I then checked it out in chrome and it worked just fine. But when I tried IE and firefox almost none of the colors or styles showed up. It looked just like basic html elements with no styling.

Comment: Ahhh, then it was probably the path of your CSS file that was in fault. The file couldn't be found, so nothing was applied

Comment: I bet if you hit F12 in Chrome and check the Dev Console window, you had the Css file missing error

Comment: Aha. So something got lost in the file transfer when I sent it in the e-mail?

Comment: It all depends on how you viewed your site from the email. If you put both files, html and css as attachments, and juste double-clicked the html file, well, of course the css will not be loaded.

Comment: I just compressed the whole thing and sent it like that. Nothing should've changed. I'm now trying it out on IE and FF straight on the laptop and still have the same problem. I used firebug on FF to see what's up and it tells me that there is no styling for any of my elements. I'm hopeful because you said it looks fine in all 3 browsers, I'm just wondering what could be the problem on my end.

Comment: I figured it out! The link to my stylesheet had "css/text". I replaced it with "text/css" and it now works. Thanks everyone for the responses and IndieRok for your dedication to the question.